# Running multiple scripts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to coding and having some difficulties, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have two different Google sheets that I'm running inside of the same project. I've successfully ran both scripts if I place the sheets in a separate projects, but they will not work if I combine them into one project. One sheet is named "Opportunity Tracker" and the other is "Mandatory Tracker. I would like the "Opportunity Tracker" to auto sort onOpen, and the "Mandatory Tracker" to auto sort onEdit. I believe I have this part set up correctly. Where I think my issue is the when the multiSortColumns() is executed. It's executing on one sheet but not the other. How to I fix the code below to allow for both to execute? Thanks again for the help.

```
SHEET_NAME = "Opportunity Tracker";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:PI21";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
{column: 2, ascending: true}
];

function onOpen(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

SHEET_NAME = "Mandatory Tracker";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:PI21";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
{column: 2, ascending: true}
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Comment: You can have only one global variable named `SHEET_NAME`.  You are redefining it.  And you can have only one function named `multiSortColumns`.  I would advise you define the variables `SHEET_NAME`, `SORT_DATA_RANGE` and `SORT_ORDER` in your `onOpen` and `onEdit` function and then pass them to `multiSortColumns(SHEET_NAME,SORT_DATA_RANGE,SORT_ORDER)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your time